# Recursive Set in OCaml

Tags: module, ocaml, recursion

how can I manage to define a `Set` in OCaml that can contains element of its type too?

To explain the problem I have a type declaration for a lot of data types like

```
type value =
  Nil
| Int of int
| Float of float
| Complex of Complex.t
| String of string
| Regexp of regexp
| Char of char
| Bool of bool
| Range of (int*int) list
| Tuple of value array
| Lambda of code
| Set of ValueSet.t (* this isn't allowed in my case since module is declared later*)
```

In addition I declare a concrete module for `ValueSet` later in the same file:

```
module ValueSet = Set.Make(struct type t = value let compare = Pervasives.compare end)
```

The problem is that `ValueSet` has `value` as it's elt type but `value` can be a `ValueSet` so I'm getting troubles while trying to compile it.

All of these declarations are contained in just a file named `types.ml` (that has it's own interface `types.mli` but without any `ValueSet` module decl since I'm not either sure it's possible).

Can this problem be solved in some way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use recursive modules. [Language manual](https://web.archive.org/web/20130825223801/http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual021.html#toc75) uses precisely the same example of recursive set type to illustrate this language feature. Below is a relevant excerpt.

> A typical example of a recursive module definition is:
>
> ```
> module rec A : sig
>                  type t = Leaf of string | Node of ASet.t
>                  val compare: t -> t -> int
>                end
>              = struct
>                  type t = Leaf of string | Node of ASet.t
>                  let compare t1 t2 =
>                    match (t1, t2) with
>                      (Leaf s1, Leaf s2) -> Pervasives.compare s1 s2
>                    | (Leaf _, Node _) -> 1
>                    | (Node _, Leaf _) -> -1
>                    | (Node n1, Node n2) -> ASet.compare n1 n2
>                end
>     and ASet : Set.S with type elt = A.t
>              = Set.Make(A)
> ```
>
> It can be given the following specification:
>
> ```
> module rec A : sig
>                  type t = Leaf of string | Node of ASet.t
>                  val compare: t -> t -> int
>                end
>     and ASet : Set.S with type elt = A.t
> ```

Comment: It seems that my OCaml compiler (3.11.0) doesn't support them yet. In any case having this kind of recursive declaration inside `types.ml` will force to have inner modules like `Types.InnerTypes` and `Types.ValueSet` which can be ok for the ValueSet but not for the other one..

Comment: I think I'm slowly managing it to work some way.. I'll probably accept your answer in a short time if I'll be able to make it work :)

Comment: OCaml has had recursive modules since 3.07.